# How to measure speed in Google Analytics for AMP pages?

Tags: performance, google-analytics, amp-html, amp-analytics

We implemented AMP to our site a couple of months ago. We're tracking visits correct in Google Analytics but the speed dimensions are empty, we have no sample pages measured.

How can I get the load time in amp pages?

In amp-analytics config I put 'site_speed_sample_rate' => 100 in order to track all the pages.

```
self::$triggers['trackPageview'] = [
            'on' => 'visible',
            'request' => 'pageview',
            'vars' => [
                'account' => $this->environment->getCodigoAnalitics(),
                'site_speed_sample_rate' => 100
            ]
        ];
```

I expect to get the load timings but all i've got is 0s in all amp pages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I may be late but hope someone might find it useful. Various AMP features allow variables to be used inside of strings and substituted with the corresponding actual values. `${contentLoadTime}` is one of them.

```
   "triggers": {
           "trackGA": {
               "selector": "amp-layout",
               "on": "visible",
               "request": "event",
               "vars": {
                 "eventAction" : "ContentLoadTime",
                 "eventCategory": "${contentLoadTime}"
               }
           }
    }
```

link to the whole list : https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md